Question about Munkres' Proof of Classification Theorem for Surfaces: Why must valid labeling schemes be proper?
In Munkres' Topology's proof of the classification theorem for surfaces, he asserts that if "w is the labeling scheme by which one forms the space X from the polygonal region P... Then w is a proper scheme of length least 4."
(A "proper labeling scheme" is one in which each label appears exactly twice in the scheme.)
However, I don't follow the logic -- why must w be a proper scheme?
Screenshot attached below. If anyone has any insight, it would be deeply appreciated.


What does the first sentence of the theorem say?
